# How to align legend in angular-chart.js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, charts, chart.js

II'm using an [**angular-chart.js**](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) chart-pie.

I need to align the legend like `horizontalAlign: "right", verticalAlign: "center"`, but I have no idea how to do it.

---

### My code

HTML:

```
<canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie"
      chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options">
</canvas>
```

Module:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("PieCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
    $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
    $scope.options = { 
        legend : { 
            display : true, 
            position : "right"
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this style to your css:

```
.chart-container {
    position: relative;
}
chart-legend {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I have edited my code. This will align your legend horizontally to the right and vertically in the middle.

**Explanation:**

The directive creates this html structure:
[image]

You can add your own style to the elements.

**Edit**
Put in html like this:

```
<style>
   .chart-container {
        position: relative;
    }
    chart-legend {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
</style>
```

**Edit 2.**

The code above works for an older version. For the newer version open the [Chart.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.js) and add this code

```
y += me.height/2 - itemHeight*me.legendItems.length/2;
```

above

```
drawLegendBox(x, y, legendItem);
```

to be more exact on line 6553.

Comment: In the output, my example generated only the `<canvas>` object but did not generate the `<ul>` list.

Comment: I will update my answer with a working jsfiddle in few minutes.